# Placing long table inside \shadowbox

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, framed, decorations

I have a multi-page table produced by long table package and I want to put each page of the `longtable` inside `\shadowbox`. Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\begin{document}
\shadowbox{\vbox{\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}\hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
..................... 
\end{longtable}}}
\end{document}
```

But then my table does not break across pages. How should I fix this?

Note that using `mdframed` is not an option for me. A solution should only use `\shadowbox` command from `fancybox` package. This is my assignment from *LaTeX writing* course that I do at my university.

**EDit:** The assignment is over. So if you can solve it, then post your solutions.

Comment: Using `mdframed` can be an option for you?

Comment: Boxes cannot be broken across pages, and so creating graphical effects around them which can be broken is pretty tricky (hence the existence of `mdframed`). I am pretty suspicious of this being the real nature of an assignment: I think a lot of experienced LaTeX users would struggle to do this in the way you put it!

Comment: @HarishKumar: I think the page-break code in `mdframed` would clash with the one of `longtable`. So this wouldn't be an option as well. I wonder if `tabu` allows something like this.

Comment: @Wright: This is indeed the actual assignment. We have to do it exactly the way I said. Our instructor said also that this is not an easy assignment. He suggested putting each chunk inside `\shadowbox`.

Comment: Your instructor has mislead you, the longtable chunks bear no resemblance the to visible units of the table that appear on each page. If you do want to do this you would have to insert the shadowbox in the longtable output routine as it re-assembles each page.

Comment: David, Can you please post this as an answer with little more explanation/code?

Comment: Well if it's an assignment, code seems inappropriate?

Comment: I put a reference to this page for my assignment. The instructor has stated that it is ok if you get helps from others provided you acknowledge them. I tried many things but none of them work. I appreciate if you help me if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

To use the command `shadowbox` you can use the package `framed` which can handle `shadowbox`:

```
\usepackage{fancybox}
\newenvironment{shadowframe}{%
  \def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep \shadowbox}%
  \MakeFramed {\FrameRestore}}%
 {\endMakeFramed}
\usepackage[]{framed}
```

**EDIT:**

Although `mdframed` isn't a solution for you I want to provide an example with his package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[shadow=true,linewidth=2pt,everyline=true]{mdframed}
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}\hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is certainly not a solution. I explicitly said in my question that any solution should only use `\shadowbox` from `fancybox` package so using `framed` package is not acceptable.

Comment: @user13617 The command `shadowbox` is used. Without the extra package you have to hack the package `longtable`. You can also write your own splitting algorithm.

Comment: Daneil: I knew before creating this post that I need to hack `longtable`. My point was that your answer does not help at all.

Answer (score 5):

You ought to modify the commands `\LT@output` and `\LT@start` from the package. The following works for the `longtable` version `[2004/02/01 v4.11]`. The biggest problem is that you cannot put `\shadowbox` directly around `\box255` which stores the page contents. Second problem is that the shadowbox would go around the text before the table at its first page. I made the shadowbox a bit narrower (1.5% from both left and right) to get a better look on the last page.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable} % version 
\makeatletter
\newlength{\LT@startpagetotal}
\def\LT@start{%
    \let\LT@start\endgraf
    \endgraf\penalty\z@\vskip\LTpre
    \dimen@\pagetotal
    \advance\dimen@ \ht\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
    \advance\dimen@ \dp\ifvoid\LT@firsthead\LT@head\else\LT@firsthead\fi
    \advance\dimen@ \ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@ii\vfuzz
    \vfuzz\maxdimen
    \setbox\tw@\copy\z@
    \setbox\tw@\vsplit\tw@ to \ht\@arstrutbox
    \setbox\tw@\vbox{\unvbox\tw@}%
    \vfuzz\dimen@ii
    \advance\dimen@ \ht
        \ifdim\ht\@arstrutbox>\ht\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
    \advance\dimen@\dp
        \ifdim\dp\@arstrutbox>\dp\tw@\@arstrutbox\else\tw@\fi
    \advance\dimen@ -\pagegoal
    \ifdim \dimen@>\z@\vfil\break\fi
        \global\@colroom\@colht
    \ifvoid\LT@foot\else
    \advance\vsize-\ht\LT@foot
    \global\advance\@colroom-\ht\LT@foot
    \dimen@\pagegoal\advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@foot\pagegoal\dimen@
    \maxdepth\z@
    \fi
    \ifvoid\LT@firsthead\relax
      \LT@startpagetotal-\ht\LT@head\relax% MODIFIED %
      \copy\LT@head
    \else
      \LT@startpagetotal-\ht\LT@firsthead\relax% MODIFIED %
      \box\LT@firsthead
    \fi\nobreak
    \advance\LT@startpagetotal\pagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
    \output{\LT@output}}
\def\LT@output{%
    \ifnum\outputpenalty <-\@Mi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty > -\LT@end@pen
        \LT@err{floats and marginpars not allowed in a longtable}\@ehc
    \else
        \setbox\z@\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv}%
        \ifdim \ht\LT@lastfoot>\ht\LT@foot
        \dimen@\pagegoal
        \advance\dimen@-\ht\LT@lastfoot
        \ifdim\dimen@<\ht\z@
            \setbox2\hbox to 0.97\textwidth{\box\@cclv\hss}%% MODIFIED %
            \ht2\dimexpr\ht2-\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
            \setbox1\hbox{\shadowbox{\box2}}%% MODIFIED %
            \ht1\dimexpr\ht1+\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
            \global\LT@startpagetotal0pt\relax% MODIFIED %
            \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\box1\copy\LT@foot\vss}%% MODIFIED %
            \@makecol
            \@outputpage
            \setbox\z@\vbox{\box\LT@head}%
        \fi
        \fi
        \global\@colroom\@colht
        \global\vsize\@colht
        \setbox2\hbox to 0.97\textwidth{\kern-0.015\textwidth\vbox% MODIFIED %
          {\unvbox\z@\box\ifvoid\LT@lastfoot\LT@foot\else\LT@lastfoot\fi}\hss}%% MODIFIED %
        \ht2\dimexpr\ht2-\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
        \setbox1\hbox{\shadowbox{\box2}}%% MODIFIED %
        \ht1\dimexpr\ht1+\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
        \global\LT@startpagetotal0pt\relax% MODIFIED %
        \noindent\box1\relax%
    \fi
    \else
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\unvbox\@cclv\copy\LT@foot}%% MODIFIED %
    \setbox2\hbox to 0.97\textwidth{\kern-0.015\textwidth\box\@cclv\hss}%% MODIFIED %
    \ht2\dimexpr\ht2-\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
    \setbox1\hbox{\shadowbox{\box2}}%% MODIFIED %
    \ht1\dimexpr\ht1+\LT@startpagetotal\relax% MODIFIED %
    \global\LT@startpagetotal0pt\relax% MODIFIED %
    \setbox\@cclv\vbox{\box1\vss}%% MODIFIED %
    \@makecol
    \@outputpage
        \global\vsize\@colroom
    \copy\LT@head\nobreak
    \fi}
\makeatother

\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-7]

%\tracingmacros=1
%\tracingonline=1
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}\hline
FIRST&HEAD\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline RUNNING&HEAD\\\hline\endhead
RUNNING&FOOT\\\hline\endfoot
LAST&FOOT\\\hline\endlastfoot
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[8-11]

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|}\hline
FIRST&HEAD\\\hline\endfirsthead
\hline RUNNING&HEAD\\\hline\endhead
RUNNING&FOOT\\\hline\endfoot
LAST&FOOT\\\hline\endlastfoot
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
Test&Test\\ \hline
\end{longtable}

\lipsum[12-15]

\end{document}
```

### How does the modification work:

We do two things: The macro `\LT@output` is the output routine for the `longtable`. This routine takes care of the page typesetting. Here we take the page contents (which is internally stored in `\box255`=`\box\@cclv`) and put `\shadowbox` around it, just not exactly, we have to fool around with `\hbox` and `\vbox` at different places to get the desired result. The problem is that for the first page of the `longtable`, this puts the text above the table into the box, which is frowned upon. Hence we modify `\LT@start` to measure the `\pagetotal` of the page when the table begins to be typeset. We do it after the table head is set so that we don't have to deal with the `\depth` of the previous contents. The length `\LT@startpageottal` is used to store this measure. Once we know how high is the text above the table, we make `\shadowbox` assume that the contents of the box are less high by this amount.

Comment: Thanks @percusse, I was missing a `\noindent` at one place.

Comment: This has only one problem. We only want table to be inside `\shadowbox` but this places both table and normal text inside `\shadowbox`. Is not there any way that we just put table inside `\shadowbox` and not the normal text?

Comment: I'll look into it.

Comment: The new version should work, I'm in a hurry now and will comment the code later.

Comment: You should comment the code @tohecz. :)

Comment: @AlexHirzel That's a little bit problem. Most of the code is copied from the file `longtable.sty`. The changes I made are marked in the code and the intentions are discuessed in the answer.